# python regex find substrings centered with numbers

Tags: python, regex, substring

I have a string. I want to cut the string up into substrings that include a number-containing word surrounded by (up to) 4 words on either side. If the substrings overlap they should combine.

```
Sampletext = "by the way I know 54 how to take praise for 65 excellent questions 34 thank you for asking appreciated."
re.findall('(\s[*\s]){1,4}\d(\s[*\s]){1,4}', Sampletext)
desired output = ['the way I know 54 how to take praise', 'to take praise for 65 excellent questions 34 thank you for asking']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Overlapping Matches: Use Lookaheads**

This will do it:

```
subject = "by the way I know 54 how to take praise for 65 excellent questions 34 thank you for asking appreciated."
for match in re.finditer(r"(?=((?:\b\w+\b ){4}\d+(?: \b\w+\b){4}))", subject):
    print(match.group(1))
```

**What is a Word?**

The output depends on your definition of a word. Here, in a word, I have allowed digits. This produces the following output.

**Output (allowing digits in words)**

```
the way I know 54 how to take praise
to take praise for 65 excellent questions 34 thank
for 65 excellent questions 34 thank you for asking
```

**Option 2: No digits in Words**

```
subject = "by the way I know 54 how to take praise for 65 excellent questions 34 thank you for asking appreciated."    
for match in re.finditer(r"(?=((?:\b[a-z]+\b ){4}\d+(?: \b[a-z]+\b){4}))", subject, re.IGNORECASE):
    print(match.group(1))
```

**Output 2**

```
the way I know 54 how to take praise
```

**Option 3: extending to four uninterrupted non-digit words**

Based on your comments, this option will extend to the left and right of the pivot until four uninterrupted non-digit words are matched. Commas are ignored.

```
subject = "by the way I know 54 how to take praise for 65 excellent questions 34 thank you for asking appreciated. One Two Three Four 55 Extend 66 a b c d AA BB CC DD 71 HH DD, JJ FF"
for match in re.finditer(r"(?=((?:\b[a-z]+[ ,]+){4}(?:\d+ (?:[a-z]+ ){1,3}?)*?\d+.*?(?:[ ,]+[a-z]+){4}))", subject, re.IGNORECASE):
    print(match.group(1))
```

**Output 3**

```
the way I know 54 how to take praise
to take praise for 65 excellent questions 34 thank you for asking
One Two Three Four 55 Extend 66 a b c d
AA BB CC DD 71 HH DD, JJ FF
```

Comment: Please meet me [in chat here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57209/discussion-between-user2104778-and-zx81)

Comment: How do I simplify the Option 3 expression so that words are defined broadly as groups of non white spaces (/S+) surrounded by white spaces (\s+). Numbers are any "word" that has a digit in it.

Comment: From your definition, a "word" could also match a "digit-word"?

Comment: yes, of course. So the only change to option 3 is to broaden the definition of digit and word.

Comment: You say "of course", but to me it's not clear at all what extending by four beyond a digit word means in these conditions where your word can also be a non-digit word

Comment: Sorry, my bad. The four words on each end of the match are non white spaces but with no digit. The "digit words" are non white space words with one or more digit. I hope that helps, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not able to get to it right now. If you need an answer fast, please post a new question. If so, I suggest you reference the first question. May have time later but not sure. :)