# python regex find substrings centered with numbers and generate combinations

Tags: python, regex, string, digit

After help on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24691695/python-regex-find-substrings-centered-with-numbers), I have a regex that:

**A.** Finds a word that contain digits, e.g. `1.2` (but that's not the final match...)

**B.** When possible, extends the match to the left and to the right up to another digit-containing word, as long as there are no more than three non-digit-containing words between each digit containing word.

**C.** Extends the match to the left and to the right to include sequences of 4 non-digit-containing words.

```
    sample = "AA AA AA AA AA AA 1.2 BB 1.2 BB 1.3 BB BB BB BB BB"
    matches = re.findall(r'(?=(\s(?:[^\d\s]+[\s]+){4}(?:[^\d\s]*\d+(?:[^\d\s]+[\s]+){1,3}?)*?[^\d\s]*\d+.*?(?:[\s]+[^\d\s]+){4}\s))', sample)
```

Match: `AA AA AA AA 1.2 BB 1.2 BB 1.3 BB BB BB BB`

Please help me modify this regex. I still want it to accomplish points A and B, and instead of C, I want to obtain all 25 sequence combinations of 0-4 trailing and starting words.

Here is my desired output:

```
"AA AA AA AA 1.2 BB 1.2 BB 1.3 BB BB BB BB"
"AA AA AA 1.2 BB 1.2 BB 1.3 BB BB BB BB"
"AA AA 1.2 BB 1.2 BB 1.3 BB BB BB BB"
"AA 1.2 BB 1.2 BB 1.3 BB BB BB BB"
"1.2 BB 1.2 BB 1.3 BB BB BB BB"
"AA AA AA AA 1.2 BB 1.2 BB 1.3 BB BB BB"
"AA AA AA 1.2 BB 1.2 BB 1.3 BB BB BB"
"AA AA 1.2 BB 1.2 BB 1.3 BB BB BB"
"AA 1.2 BB 1.2 BB 1.3 BB BB BB"
"1.2 BB 1.2 BB 1.3 BB BB BB"
"AA AA AA AA 1.2 BB 1.2 BB 1.3 BB BB"
"AA AA AA 1.2 BB 1.2 BB 1.3 BB BB"
"AA AA 1.2 BB 1.2 BB 1.3 BB BB"
"AA 1.2 BB 1.2 BB 1.3 BB BB"
"1.2 BB 1.2 BB 1.3 BB BB"
"AA AA AA AA 1.2 BB 1.2 BB 1.3 BB"
"AA AA AA 1.2 BB 1.2 BB 1.3 BB"
"AA AA 1.2 BB 1.2 BB 1.3 BB"
"AA 1.2 BB 1.2 BB 1.3 BB"
"1.2 BB 1.2 BB 1.3 BB"
"AA AA AA AA 1.2 BB 1.2 BB 1.3"
"AA AA AA 1.2 BB 1.2 BB 1.3"
"AA AA 1.2 BB 1.2 BB 1.3"
"AA 1.2 BB 1.2 BB 1.3"
"1.2 BB 1.2 BB 1.3"
```

Ideally this would be accomplished using the initial regex.

Comment: you cant handle nesting well with regex in  general for quotes or parens or anything else

Comment: hmm so maybe the way to go is find the string with the regex above and then manually split it up?

Comment: Hey there, it's been a while and I don't remember what the old regex does, so can we please start fresh? I'm not understanding the requirements in this question (what the combinations in the output represent, the "English formula" to generate them). Can you please  explain in more detail? The question already has 4 close votes, and I'm worried it will get closed because people are not understanding what you're asking (for instance I'm not understanding...)

Comment: Hey, your question was closed. I tried to edit it to clarify it. Once you feel it's completely clear, you can write to the people who close it to consider reopening it, or flag it for moderation.

Answer (score 2):

Let's look at a solution in pseudo-code so we don't get bogged down in specifics—especially as I may have misunderstood the spec.

As I understand it, the combinations you want to generate will be built around pivot points.

1. **Identify each pivot and the longest "wings"**. To do so, build a regex of that matches `(G1)(Pivot)(G2)`, where captures G1 and G2 are the longest allowable extensions ("wings") around the pivot.
2. **Build the combinations in code with two for loops.** In code, split G1 and G2 into words, and build all possible combinations with two nested for loops.

**Sample Regex for Pivot and Wings**

In [the demo](http://regex101.com/r/nJ8cJ8/26), you can inspect Groups 1, 2 and 3. The pivot is the first `1.2`. The left wing is `AA AA AA AA`. The right wing is `BB 1.2 BB 1.3 BB BB BB BB`.

Note that by making the `.*?` greedy, we obtain a different match. In that case, the pivot is `1.3`, the left wing is `AA AA AA AA 1.2 BB 1.2 BB` and the right wing is `BB BB BB BB` (see [demo](http://regex101.com/r/nJ8cJ8/27)).

Here's a bit of code to get you started.

```
import re
subject = "AA AA AA AA AA AA 1.2 BB 1.2 BB 1.3 BB BB BB BB BB"
myregex = r"""(?x)
(          # Start Group 1: the left wing
   # The four first words
   (?:[^\d\s]+[ ]){4}
   # The optional digit-non-digit groups
   (?:
        \S*\d\S*[ ]                  # a digit-containing word
        (?:[^\d\s]+){1,3}[ ]        # 1 to 3 non-digit words
   )*?
)        # Close Group 1 (the left wing)

# The Pivot
(\S*\d\S*)

(             # Start Group 2: the right wing
# Get to the Last Required Digit Word
   (?:
     (?:[ ][^\d\s]+){1,3}        # 1 to 3 non-digit words
     [ ]\S*\d\S*                  # a digit-containing word
   )*
# The four last words
(?:[ ][^\d\s]+){4}
)              # End Group 2: the right wing
"""
match = re.search(myregex,subject)
leftwing = match.group(1)
pivot = match.group(2)
rightwing = match.group(3)
wordregex = re.compile("\S+")
print("Left Wing Tokens: ",wordregex.findall(leftwing))
print("Pivot: ", pivot)
print("Left Wing Tokens: ",wordregex.findall(rightwing))
print("Now it's up to you to write the loops to build the combinations!")
```

**Output**

```
Left Wing Tokens:  ['AA', 'AA', 'AA', 'AA']
Pivot:  1.2
Left Wing Tokens:  ['BB', '1.2', 'BB', '1.3', 'BB', 'BB', 'BB', 'BB']
Now it's up to you to write the loops to build the combinations!
```

Comment: FYI: Added sample code to get you started.

Comment: Thanks, though it breaks down under different strings, like strings with adjacent digit containing words. Anyway, I have moved on from trying to attempt a purely regex approach and have a solution using a combination of a regex and nested for loop.